# How do I add a css class in a GM-script?

Tags: jquery, greasemonkey

I found out that this is the way to style all images on a site.

```
GM_addStyle("img { border: 3px dotted green;background-color: red; }");
```

How do I style just a few?
Is there a way to add a class to the GM_addStyle so that I can call this class later with jQuery like .addClass('myClass')?

Thank you in advance for your help and time for answering the question.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes,

```
GM_addStyle(".myClass { border: 3px dotted green;background-color: red; }");
```

will create a class style that you can then add via jQuery's `.addClass('myClass')`.

.
Note:  you can add more than 1 style with each `GM_addStyle` statement, too.  Like:

```
GM_addStyle
(
   '.ClearFloats                                            \
    {                                                       \
        clear:              both;                           \
    }                                                       \
    .HideIt                                                 \
    {                                                       \
        display:            none;                           \
    }                                                       \
    .StayOpaque                                             \
    {                                                       \
        opacity:            1 !important;                   \
    }                                                       \
   '
);
```

etc.

Comment: Thank you, Brock Adams. I didn't know that about adding more than 1 style. You probably saved a lot of my time.

Answer (score 2):

```
GM_addStyle((<><![CDATA[
    .myClass {
        border: 3px dotted green;
        background-color: red;
    }
]]></>).toString());
```

This way you don't need to end each line with `\`